# How do you keep relative positioning from poping out of the box?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to use relative positioning for other reasons, and data in my div is popuping out of the container div in ie7.

Can you guys give me some idea what is going?

Also, I can just remove position: relative;.   That is need for my line highlighting code.

Thanks,
Grae

Here is the code:

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
<html>
<head>`

</head>
<body>
    <div style="overflow:auto; height:350px; border: 1px solid #00ff00">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div style="position:relative;">
                        <PRE>
Test Line
Test Line
Test Line
Test Line
Test Line
Test Line
Test Line
Test Line
Test Line
Test Line
Test Line
Test Line
Test Line
Test Line
Test Line
Test Line
Test Line
Test Line
Test Line
Test Line
Test Line
Test Line
Test Line
Test Line
                        </PRE>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

Comment: @Flack I provided it now

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add `overflow: hidden;` to your inline (or CSS) style for the containing element.

Comment: I would still like the used to be able to scroll through the content.

Comment: you can use `overflow:auto` then

Comment: @Phil I am not sure which DIV you want me to add overflow:hidden too.

Comment: @Dan Basically, I am using overlofw:auto.  I am tried overflow:auto on the other div, and it did not do anything.

Comment: If you want to scroll through the content, you will need to decide what height to fix your containing element at, and then add `overflow: scroll;` to your style declaration.

Comment: You add the styles to the `<div style="position:relative;">` element, immediately preceding the `<pre>` tag.

Comment: @Grae Oh, sorry for that, I did not see it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the following is a valid solution for you, but it worked for me.

You can add `position:relative` to your first div. (The one with the `overflow:auto`)

P.S. removing the `width="100%"` attribute from the table, or just reducing the width, will remove the horizontal scroll.